# Testing node phantom script using jasmine

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs

What is the best way to test nested asynchronous phantomjs script using jasmine.   I have tried using spyOn with single asynchronous request which works fine. But how to test nested. I am using node-phantom and have below page structure. I want to test this using jasmine.

```
 phantom.create(function(ph){
  ph.createPage(function (page){
   page.onConsoleMessage(function(msg){
       ...

   });

   page.open(config[server].script_url, function(status){
       ......

   });
```